# Find symlinks to certain directory or one of its subdirs

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

Is there an easy way to show whether there are any symlinks in a specified path **pointing to a certain directory or one of its children?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple and fast approach, assuming that you have the target as absolute path (`readlink(1)` may help with that matter):

```
find $PATH -type l -xtype d -lname "$DIR*"
```

This finds all symlinks (`-type l`) below `$PATH` which link to a directory (`-xtype d`) with a name starting with `$DIR`.

---

Another approach, which is O(n*m) and therefore may take ages and two days:

```
find $DIR -type d | xargs -n1 find $PATH -lname
```

The first `find` lists `$DIR` and all its subdirectories which are then passed (`xargs`), one at a time (`-n1`), to a second `find` which looks for all symlinks originating below `$PATH`.

---

To sum things up: **`find(1)`** is your friend.

Comment: find $PATH -type l -lname "$DIR*"

Comment: find $PATH -type l -lname "$DIR*" -exec ls -l {} \;

Answer (score 5):

Following up on [the answer given by earl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883870/434980):

`-xtype` does not work on Mac OSX, but can be safely omitted:

```
find $PATH -type l -lname "$DIR*"
```

Example:

```
find ~/ -type l -lname "~/my/sub/folder/*"
```

Comment: `-xtype` is used to find symbolic links when `-L` (old days `-follow`) is on. `-xtype` is afaik is a GNU extension. And you are correct. It can be safely omitted since `-L` is not used. One think though `-type d` will give directories only and `-type l -type d` will give symbolic links to directories only.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the findbl (bad links) script in fslint. It might give you some hints:
http://code.google.com/p/fslint/source/browse/trunk/fslint/findbl